# What benefit is there to obfuscate the geometry with algebra?

Tags: secondary-education, geometry, general-pedagogy

Consider:

> In a right triangle:
>
> sin(2x + 4) = cos (46)
>
> What is the value of x?

The question above is from standardized tests for a geometry course. If my goal is to have students understand cofunctions, what benefit is there to force students to do algebra? It seems that we are making geometry harder than it needs to be.

And I guess this could probably apply to other fields of math?

I can understand analysis courses requiring topology but the topology is taught with regards to the analysis and not as pure topology.

Comment: I agree that it's pretty silly to ask a question that mixes things together. I suppose the best students will stand out. What level is this being asked at?

Comment: Being able to understand, analyze, and solve such functional relationships is important in certain contexts. Perhaps the contexts comprised by the standardized tests are broader than the context you posit. (I don't know anything about the tests from which this problem comes.)

Comment: @SueVanHattum high school level but should college level be any different?

Comment: AP test for calculus, or standardized test that all students take, or ...?

Comment: What’s a cofunction?

Comment: Can you explain why you assume the question is about geometry and why an algebraic understanding of cofunctions is not valuable? In other words, what's not algebraic about cos(x) = sin(pi/2-x)?

Comment: @ToddWilcox its from a geometry specific course standardized test

Comment: *If my goal is to have students understand cofunctions* --- The question seems to me more about being able to APPLY cofunction identities, not understanding them or regurgitating them. Also, while $2x+4$ is a bit artificial, this is similar to what one often encounters in practice (later math, physics, engineering, etc.) -- in applying something like $\sin \theta = \cos (\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta),$ it's often (mostly?) the case that the "$\theta$" isn't just $\theta.$

Comment: @user3840170 *co*sine, *co*secant, and *co*tangent (along with their esoteric cousins *co*versin and ex*co*secant) are collectively called the "*co*functions." Some teachers stress to students that the term "cosine" should remind one "sine of *co*mplement," (and so on, for all three/five pairs) and find differentiating the "natural" functions from the cofunctions useful. Others never comment on it.

Comment: One reason for doing this is to make it more of a challenge than to type the function into your smart phone (or smart watch...). If the question were merely "sin(x)=cos(46), find x," that's two seconds on a smart phone and no proof at all that anything was learned. (I understand that smart phones, etc., aren't allowed during standardized testing... but are we collecting those smart watches? I'm simply making a point.)

Comment: What are the units of the 46?  Did you mean 46 degrees (46°)?  If so, you should include the units.  In this context, an angle whose units are unlabelled is likely to be interpreted as being in radians.  46 radians is approximately 2,635° 36' 21".  In this problem (where there is no damping as the number of cycles increases), that is equivalent to 115° 36' 21".

Comment: @Jasper in a right triangle the assumption is in degrees, you cannot possibly have 46 radians in an Euclidean triangle

Comment: @Lenny — I take it you have never taken an electrical engineering course.

Comment: @Jasper Okay but this isn't electrical engineering

Comment: @Lenny — To answer your unstated bigger question: Don't use this standardized test if you don't have to. The authors do not understand common applications for trigonometry, such as surveying, physics, and engineering, not to mention the applications you are used to. The first three are applications where algebra does get mixed into the arguments of trigonometric functions -- and they need units to be handled carefully. Whereas the applications you are used to do not mix algebra into the arguments of trigonometric functions.

Comment: @Lenny Thanks and I've deleted my previous Comment, because I twisted my fingers when I mean to ask rather 'How would Sin(X) be algebra…' Sorry that leaves your response without a reason.

Comment: @Jasper most people can't even handle units anyway. Most people don't understand the difference between millimeters and centimeters. I mean most of real life like construction uses degrees when students are introduced to the concept of radians, they get confused because radians is mostly math, physics and engineering.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Is your ultimate goal *really* just to teach cofunctions?

Or are you trying to teach cofunctions so that the students can apply them later?

---

I am speaking as a student rather than an educator, but math, just as most subjects, is taught incrementally with more advanced concepts building on simpler concepts. All mathematics was invented to solve problems in the real world. Showing that a student can apply their knowledge of different concepts in isolation has little practical use. The real world is not a controlled laboratory environment where specific disciplines can be controlled and used in isolation. Only the simplest real-world problems can be solved by applying a single concept by itself.

---

Anecdotally, when I was in high school, I was continually surprised by the number of my classmates that would excel in advanced math and science courses yet struggle tremendously when multiple math concepts needed to be applied in conjunction, particularly with word problems. Well meaning educators *do* test concepts in isolation in order not to confuse students or "obfuscate" the problem, but it's my opinion that this will only serve to set the student up for failure in the future.

Comment: (+1) *so that the students can apply them later* --- I scanned the answers before writing my comment above, so it's possible I stole "apply" from your answer, although as I was writing my comment I originally didn't mention "apply", which was introduced during some later editing of my comment, and while I wasn't specifically thinking of your answer at the time, it may have been in my unconscious. (My comment originally had the simple harmonic motion example of rewriting $A\cos \omega t + B\sin \omega t$ as $C\cos(\omega t + \delta),$ then I realized this involved some more sophisticated trig.)

Comment: @DaveLRenfro we easily could have come up with the same word. I think it's the logical conclusion to make

Comment: This is the kind of answer I would like to be articulate enough to post myself.  I strongly object to the OP's use of "obfuscate" in the title, as if that's a bad thing.  This kind intermixing of concepts of what educators SHOULD be doing. It's about *problem solving.*

Comment: +1 I strongly agree with this answer except for the sentence *"All mathematics was invented to solve problems in the real world"*. This is probably true (at least to a large extent) for the kind of mathematics that this question is about, but claiming this for *all* mathematics is certainly too strong.

Comment: @JochenGlueck fair enough. again, not an educator, so maybe it just seemed that way to me in the fields of math that I actually studied (but also, I'm a certified university drop out, so that's not saying too much). I wouldn't be surprised if there are levels of mathematics that are more theoretical and do not have any currently known applicability

Comment: @JochenGlueck although even if these branches of mathematics have no *currently* known applicability, they may be studied to address anticipated future problems or even to create a model that serves no purpose other than to prove or unify one or more existing concepts that are understood to work but not *why* they work. (I'm just speculating though. Your profile suggests you have far more expertise in this area than I.)

Comment: 100% on this answer. Especially US schools (thanks standardized testing), but very widely elsewhere too, teachers just teach the material and be done with it, but that is in most cases absolutely not the actual point of the class.

Answer (score 23):

Tests seek to measure ability. Math ability, like most other forms of ability (including athletic ability), isn't solely dependent on one's ability to execute individual skills in isolation -- it also depends on one's ability to strategically combine skills.

Your goal might just be for your students to understand cofunctions, but the goal of the test is to also measure students' abilities to strategically combine that skill with other skills.

Answer (score 18):

This multi-step question requires students to understand and apply multiple concepts or strategies to solve the problem. The goal of a standardized test is not to provide a correctly-sequenced list of questions that leads students to conceptual understanding; instead, tests need to include more difficult questions in order to distinguish between two students with above-average levels of ability. Ideally, students would have learned these concepts before approaching this problem. If a student is not able to solve the related equation $\mathrm{sin}(y) = \mathrm{cos}(46)$, then he or she is not ready to solve this one. In fact, one "strategy" to solving this problem would be to first solve the simpler equation and then assuming $y = 2x+4$, solve for $x$. This strategy effectively separates the issues for the student.

Comment: Indeed, I think many students would be able to solve $\sin(y) = \cos(46)$ by blindly copying a procedure from their textbook with only a superficial understanding, and the "obfuscation" of asking them to solve $\sin(2x+4) = \cos(46)$ will help them get a deeper understanding of what they're doing.

Answer (score 9):

I have been on committees that write questions for standardized tests and placement tests. In this role, I have reviewed results of many trigonometry questions that were piloted and then revised for re-piloting, removed for future piloting all together, or approved for inclusion as a graded test item.

If this were piloted in the form of a multiple-choice question, I would expect the [point-biserial correlation test score](https://testing.wisc.edu/whatdonumbersmean.html) would raise lots of red flag!

The first thing that made me cringe with this question is probably just professional baggage: I got hung up quickly on the 46. I spent too much mental energy wondering if somebody meant $46^{\circ}$ instead of 46 radians. After all, $46$ is close to $45$ and $45^{\circ}$ is nice. The strangeness of the integer 46 was a big distraction for me. I got over it, and said to myself that  in the spirit of the *Douglas Adams answer to the universe*, too bad it was not 42. Oh well.

But I did not get over it gracefully! The darn integer 46 and $\cos(46)$ made me start thinking about $\arcsin(\cos(46))$. Embarrassing. I thought to myself, "I mean really, $\cos(46)$ has no prospects for a future."

Eventually I realized I should think in terms of $\sin(\theta)=\cos(46)$ and then $$\sin(\theta)=\cos(\theta+\pi/2)=\cos(46)$$ and then I knew I was on the right path, finally. I was still annoyed with the manifest radian context with the $\pi$ on the left side and that thing I thought might be a misprint for $46$ degrees on the right.

Then the results are still messy and kind of tricky for most students:

$$\theta=2k\pi+\frac{27\pi}{2}+46$$
or
$$\theta=2k\pi+\frac{29\pi}{2}-46$$ for $k\in{\bf Z}$

Yikes! And I still have to come back and fiddle with the substitution $\theta=2x+4$.

My guess is that if this question were piloted on a standardized test, it would come back with very poor results and beg for some revisions and extensive repiloting before being allowed on the exam for grading.

Observation: if the 46 was indeed supposed to be $46^{\circ}$ then the solutions for $\theta$ (in radians) would be cleaner:

$$\theta=2k\pi+\frac{34\pi}{45}$$

or
$$\theta=2k\pi+\frac{11\pi}{45}$$ for $k\in{\bf Z}$.

Comment: I just assumed everything was supposed to be in degrees, which is even more likely now that we know this was in a geometry section (maybe before radians are even introduced). In that case I don't think there's any reason to switch to radians for the answer. Since this was a standardized test though, we're only seeing part of the question. I wonder what the answer choices were.

Comment: @Thierry you are probably correct. In degrees we would have $\theta=360k+136$ or $\theta=360k+44$ which seems brighter. And this plays nicely with the substitution $\theta=2x+4$.

Comment: In context of a right triangle, the only valid value for k is zero,  $0<2k\pi +\frac{34\pi}{45} <\frac\pi2$

Comment: @nicalh yes but the original question did not include the context of a right triangle. Originally it just read “solve $\sin(2x + 4) = \cos (46)$.”

Comment: That's definitely a downside of stackExchange.  The problems often evolve sometime invalidating answers.  I've been known to do that myself- post a question and over a day or two revise the question, explaining more thoroughly what I understand, don't understand, etc.
In my case, I try to caution others, the question will be revised.

Comment: When I post questions, I frequently answers quickly to ultimately share with my tutoring students, then revise and add finer points as I have time.

Answer (score 0):

The goal IS NOT "to teach cofunctions".
Trig functions are taught as a package and the relationships between them are usually taught as Pythagorean identities AND NOT as defining a cofun in terms of the original fun.  Standardized tests are not always competently designed -- the "in a right triangle" context has no bearing on the problem or its  solution -- sin and cos retain an inherently Pythagorean relationship to each other even when they are defined by other methods.
Moreover, the algebra in 2x+4 isn't there to obscure anything -- "Algebra 1" is normally taught in the semester *immediately* preceding geometry, and  a standardized test can be trying to confirm the progress through one to the other -- it can be testing whether you know how to solve 2x-4 = whatever, AND whether you know how to compute whatever from 46°. Also, the fact the question is quoted without SAYING ° opens a completely separate can of worms, which becomes a barrel if the test itself didn't clarify that in the original.